# React with Socket.io first request in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io, use-effect

I am using `Socket.io` in `react` app. I would like to do first request immediately after app loads so I put my first `emit` in `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("getCollectionsAndVolumes", socket.id);
  }, []);
```

but it doesn't work. It does not do any request. So I realized that a problem is because maybe socket is not connected yet so I put little `timeout` like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const initialGetTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      clearTimeout(initialGetTimeout);
    }, 1000);
  })
```

and it works but it is only a workaround, how should I trigger first request right after app loads? Is there any other way to do that in `React`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter which gets changed when socket is connected as a dependency for useEffect `React.useEffect(()=>{},[dependencies]);`, if there is no such parameter, then try creating a state that maintains if socket is connected or not.

Comment: I want to make it only once, if I will pass a parameter it will execute it each time it will change and I don't know which parameter should I put in dependency array

Comment: Create a state that will change only once when socket gets connected successfully, like initially set value to false and once socket is connected set it to true and then never change the value again i.e. add a condition for setstate, if value is true for state don't change

Comment: yes but I do not know how can I check if socket is connected

Comment: Which means to say code doesn't know when socket will get connect or if it's connected or not too?
if so, then there is nothing based on which you can execute 'socket.emit("getCollectionsAndVolumes", socket.id);'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that by using:

```
socket.on("connect", () => {
  socket.emit("getCollectionsAndVolumes", socket.id);
});
```

so when it is `true` it immediately executes request

Answer (score 0):

Try to monitor socket with useEffect then add 'connect' listener. Inside that listener, create a callback function to emit first request.

```
// Websocket Listener
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleCode = (res) => {
      setCode(res.code)
    }

    // Listeners
    socket.on('res_mvp_code', handleCode)
    // Join room
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      socket.emit('req_mvp_join', { room: 'mvp-1' }) // this is your first request
    })

    // Unlisteners
    return () => {
      socket.off('res_mvp_code', handleCode)
    }
  }, [socket])
```